# Calculated Property in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I stuck with a problem I have been looking for a solution to, but without much luck.

Using Entity Framework Code First, I need the ability to create a calculated property that does not rely on loading all of the objects before calculating.

```
// Psuedo Code for what I need
public class GoodInventoryChange
{
    public int GoodID { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; } // Amount of change
    public DateTime OccurredAt { get; set; } // Timestamp of the change
    public double RunningTotal { get { /* CODE TBD*/ } } // Prior record plus amount
}
```

All of the suggestions on how to do this that I have found require calling .ToList() or similar, which may require many 1000s of records to be loaded in order to find a single entry.

In the end, I need the ability to query for:

```
// Psuedo Code
int goodID = 123;
var lowestRunningTotal = (from item in Context.GoodInventoryChanges
                          where item.GoodID == goodID && DateTime.Now <= item.OccurredAt
                          orderby item.RunningTotal 
                          select item).FirstOrDefault();
```

I am using RunningTotal as an example here, but I have about 15-20 fields that need to be calculated in a similar fashion.

Does anyone have any advice or direction to point me in? I know I can brute force it, but I am hoping to do it via the SQL layer of Entity Framework.

I am OK creating calculated fields in the DB if there is a nice way to map them to Entity Framework classes as well.

Comment: The critical bit is in the words "Prior record". That requires external input so it is impossible to encapsulate the computed property in the `GoodInventoryChange` class. This is typically something to do in a separate query or in a dedicated domain model. For computed properties that can be encapsulated you could look at [DelegateDecompiler](https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler).

Comment: What about using Views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use computed columns in the database, and decorate your entity with DatabaseGenerated attribute to prevent EF to try to write back its value to the table. After load, EF will read its value when you insert or update:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]    
public string YourComputedProperty { get; set; }
```

Comment: I finally got back to this task and this worked like a dream. Thank you! :)